# Display a PDF in the .NET WebBrowser control in Adobe Reader with all options

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have used webbrowser wpf control for display PDF file. I have written code as below,

**Xaml :**

```
<WebBrowser Margin="0,60,0,0" x:Name="pdfviewer"></WebBrowser>
```

**C# :**

```
string viewerLocation = "http://www.dom.om/file.pdf";
pdfviewer.Navigate(viewerLocation);
```

I need to show File, edit, view, Help, Tools, Window, Document option bar in adobe as below image. Because I need to show option to rotate the file.

[image]

Please suggest how to enable highlighted portion in webbrowser.

I have checked below link for display PDF in webbrowser control.

[How can I hide the Adobe Reader toolbar when displaying a PDF in the .NET WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515248/how-can-i-hide-the-adobe-reader-toolbar-when-displaying-a-pdf-in-the-net-webbro)

Comment: Hi Any one please help me..