# Interact with AdobeReader plugin in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, acrobat, adobe-reader

I'm using `WebBrowser` to show `PDF` files.

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="Browser"/>
```

---

```
Browser.Navigate("C:\\Foo.pdf#page=2&view=Fit&toolbar=0&scrollbar=0");
```

By setting startup parameters (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4516157/6229375) it is possible to change the layout of the `adobe reader plugin`.

It is possible to ineract with the plugin after it has been loaded in the `WebBrowser`? For example jump to page x?!

The user has to change the pages by tap left or right (on screen). When using <kbd>Page down</kbd> or <kbd>Page up</kbd> I have two problems:

1. The user has no `Keyboard`. Only a touch monitor
2. The page does not fit exactly anymore after some page changes

---

Adobe Parameter list:

- https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: There are other ways to embed PDF, though they come with their own limitations. I don't know if it's appropriate for your application, but it is possible to embed a PDF into a windows form or WPF application via use of embedding a COM control. The limitation of course being that you cannot hide the nav pane.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18890500/1768303) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround solution to fix the following problems:

> The page does not fit exactly anymore after some page changes

Change the default settings in the adobe reader to "only one page per view".

> The user has no Keyboard. Only a touch monitor

Simulate the Keyboard events